# How do I ensure that users always enter the app where they left off?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

Through testing, I was fairly confident that clicking the launcher icon always took the user back to where they left off. However, I loaded my app after keeping it in the background for a long time and found myself on the home screen. When I pressed `back`, I was taken to the screen I had expected to return to. Things then got messy a I navigated up the activity backstack and found multiple instances of multiple screens. Did this happen because the "current" activity was `destroyed` by Android? If so, how do I handle that?

My activity hierarchy is similar to League > Division > Team > Player > Injury, so everything but Injury is a parent. I always want the user to be able to resume from any activity. Maybe I should use `launchMode="singleInstance"`? Should I use it on all activities?

In summary,

- I currently declare `launchMode="singleTop"` for every activity that is a parent, as this initially seemed to cause the user to enter from where they left off.
- How *should* I be handling my activities so that there is never more than one instance and so that the user always enters where they left off?

Answer (score 0):

Try using sharedpreferences and check if it has value then go to a certain main-page.

Comment: Do you mean check a sharedpreference to see if my activity has been destroyed and--if so--return to my main screen? Would I set that sharedPreference in my `onDestroy'? If so, then wouldn't it trigger every time my orientation is changed?